# how could I set a different background color to the menu title for every menu item or depending on the article that is opened?

Tags: css, joomla, menu, module, joomla2.5

I'm working on a Joomla 2.5 based website.
i have a submenu with a title (the title is the name of the topmenu category) on top. This title has a background color. Now I want to have a different background color (of the title) on every page that I open.
I thought about creating a extra menu module for every menu item with a specific color defined in the css, but than I have to rename every module because I must not have the same name twice. But I need the title to be the same as the Topmenu category for all the submenu items.

here is the basic structure of the generated code:

```
    <body>
    <div id="content">
    <div id="breadcrumbs"></div>
    <div id="main" class="centerAndRight"></div>
    <div id="right">
    <div class="moduletable_servicemenu">
    <h3>HERE IS THE TITLE</h3>
    <ul class="menu"></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="moduletable_kontaktmodul"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end content -->
    <div id="overallfooter"></div>
    </body>
```

Could anybody help me with an idea, please.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Could you please post some code?

Answer (score 0):

If you place a class on that title (e.g. `class="title"`), and then place a different class on the `body` tag of each page (e.g. `<body class="contact">`) you can easily style the title differently on each page, such as:

```
.contact .title {background: red}
.about .title {background: blue}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific about working on a Joomla based website. I just put it in the tags.

Comment: So I have some limitations on what classes I can put in there

Comment: The problem is, that I can adresse the "main"-div for every menu item with a different class (from the backend) but not the "right"-div. And because it is on the same level it it will not be inherited to it either. So I need some deeper Joomla knowledge to get this done. thanx

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this script for random images, it can be edited to apply towards your desire which is random colors. Its fairly simple and again you can do as many colors as you want, and the program will randomize them.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var colors = ['#ccc', '#dedede', '#333', '#555' /***keep adding as many colors***/];

    $(".Topcategory").each(function(){
    $(this).css({'background' : ' + colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)] + ')'})
    });

 });
```

Comment: thank you! But I want to specify the color for every submenu item. And it would be awesome if I could do this from the backend of Joomla.

Comment: The beauty of Joomla is extensive plugin market, im sure if you browse the market you will find what you are looking for. I must have missread your post, pardon me.